# Mac OS 10.8.3 Lion vmware virtual machine doesn't detects darwin.iso file to install VmTools?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vmware-workstation

I just installed MacOS 10.8.3 Lion in a vmware virtual machine, and I want to install Xcode but when I get to the CD/DVD IDE settings and select the darwin.iso file to install vmTools and click "connect" nothing happens, the virtual machine doesn't detects the new "disc" that I just connected. Do you know how I can solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can normally install VMware Tools by selecting Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools and running the installer on the VMware Tools volume.

If there is an error about the device being in use, try ejecting other volumes (like Mac OS X Install ESD) first.

See [VMware KB: Installing VMware Tools in a Mac OS Guest](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032440).